# Java recursive System.out.println()

Tags: java, recursion, printing, character

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    printeaza(c, scan);
}

public static char printeaza(char c, Scanner sc) {
    c = sc.next().charAt(0);
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(printeaza(c, sc));
        return c;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}
}
```

What i'm trying to do is type letters from the keyboard and  then have them diplayed in reverse. I know it can be made very easy with a for loop and char arrays but i'm curious about making it recursively and using only one char variable. I almost made it but it seems it prints all but the first letter.

So if I type: "a s d f" instead of "f d s a" i get only "f d s". I think I know why, it's because the Println statement it's only inside the if statement but I kind of run of ideeas about how to make the function "catch" the first letter as well. I hope you can have a look, thanks!

Comment: `printeaza` doesn't need a char parameter. The first thing you do in the method is overwrite it.

Comment: Use a Java debugger.  You shouldn't need to ask other people to debug your code for you.  If you don't know how, then learn ...

Comment: I wasn't asking people to debug the code for me I was just asking for an ideea because I was stuck. I am not very experienced in "thinking with recursion". Anyway thanks for saying nothing. You get points for just replying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a call to `printeaza` doesn't print its own character, only that of it's recursive call.

In other words, `printeaza(c, scan);` in `main` needs to be changed to `System.out.println(printeaza(c, scan);`

Also, I would just like to point out that using recursive calls for user input like this is not a very good idea to be honest. :/

Answer (score 3):

Your first call to `printeaza(c, scan)` (made from `public static void main`) needs to be wrapped with a `System.out.println(..)` as well.

Like this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(printeaza(c, sc)); // <-- changed line
    }

    public static char printeaza(char c, Scanner sc) {
        c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(printeaza(c, sc));
            return c;
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Incorporating Cruncher's advise, I'd write it like this:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(printeaza(sc));
    }

    public static char printeaza(Scanner sc) {
        char c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(printeaza(sc));
        } 
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks for the detailed answer.